# Installing honeyd on linux

Tags: linux, networking, honeypot

I am very new to linux and Iam just following online instructions on how to install honeyd on  linux machine. I downloaded the tar.gz file. extracted it and then configure. but when it comes to the make stage. an eroor show that make:*** no targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

I manage to install the pre requisite like libevent using the same method. libpcap on the other hand has the make:*** error too but I manage to install it using sudo apt-get command. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the complete error output.

Maybe the honeyd FAQ is a starting point for you http://www.honeyd.org/faq.php#compile_error

Answer (score 0):

There was an error when you can ./configure, so the Makefile didn't get generated. Paste the last dozen lines or so of the ./configure output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Debian based Linux distribution, the easiest way is to install `honeyd` as a `.deb` package. F.e. like this:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/honeyd/honeyd_1.5c-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i honeyd_1.5c-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Then you can install `rrdtool` with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install rrdtool
```

... and adjust the configuration files `/etc/default/honeyd` and `/etc/honeypot/honeyd.conf`